# Remove HTML onchange code using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below code snippet has **HTML onchange attribute** as well as **jQuery's change event** on the input text. I want only the **jQuery's change event** to be effective. I tried using both [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) without luck.

Could somebody please help?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#testInput").unbind("change").bind("change",function(){
    console.log("jQuery change");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="testInput" type="text" onchange="console.log('change');"/>
```

Comment: what are you going to achieve from this? i'm confused

Comment: I've to do this to discourage use of onchange attribute and make it not work even if present in code.

Comment: removeAttr('onchange'.....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the "previous" onchange event, use 
  `$("#testInput").removeAttr("onchange")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#testInput").removeAttr("onchange")
  $("#testInput").unbind("change").bind("change", function() {
    console.log("jQuery change");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="testInput" type="text" onchange="console.log('change');" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove onchange attribute. `removeAttr('onchange')` will remove onchange attribute

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").each(function(){    
     $(this).removeAttr('onchange');
  });
  $("input").bind("change",function(){
    console.log("jQuery change");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="testInput" type="text" onchange="console.log('change');"/>
<input id="testInput2" type="text" onchange="console.log('change');"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could set the `onchange` to null and add listener, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //remove inline 'onchange' event by setting it to null
    $("#testInput")[0].onchange = null;

    $(document).on("change" "#testInput", function(){
      console.log("jQuery change");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('change','#testInput',function(){
    console.log("jQuery change");
  });
});
```